# Cucumber on Linux vs Cucumber on Windows - Need to know the pros and cons

Tags: linux, cucumber, bdd

I am not sure whether there are any specific advantages/disadvantages of using Cucumber on Linux over Cucumber on Windows. Can someone elaborate the pros and cons? Also, kindly share some trusted links for Cucumber on Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cucumber framework is written in Ruby, so any advantages / disadvantages aren't connected to the framework itself, but to the use of Ruby on either Linux or Windows.

Lots of people find Linux-based development easier than Windows-based development. The only reason I'd use Windows is if it was being used in combination with something Windows-based, like C#, or you happen to have a Windows machine already. At that point you might as well go with a C# tool like SpecFlow instead, or you could easily dual-boot to Linux.

Having said that, I use a Windows machine almost exclusively, and have run Cucumber workshops with people with Windows machines. It's fine. And the most popular tool for devs these days is a Macbook, so YMMV.

Similarly, you won't find "trusted links for Cucumber on Linux" because it's just Ruby. If you can get Ruby running, you can get Cucumber running. The only trusted link you really need is [the front page](https://cucumber.io/).